# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (33,4) (33,)

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

This is my code and i am unable to implement multiple linear regression. I am trying to implement it using gradient descent and getting an error in theta = theta - (learn/len(xtrain)) * np.sum(xtrain * (xtrain @ theta.T - ytrain), axis=0). Can someone please help. I am new to python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')


x_points = dataset.iloc[:,0:3]
y_points = dataset.iloc[:,4].values
ones = np.ones([x_points.shape[0],1])
x_points = np.concatenate((ones,x_points),axis=1)


x_points = (x_points - x_points.mean())/x_points.std()
y_points = (y_points - y_points.mean())/y_points.std()


from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(x_points,y_points,test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)


theta = np.zeros(4)
learn = 0.001 # .001, .01, .1, 1
iters = 100

#computecost
def computeCost(xtrain,y,theta):
    tobesummed = np.power(((xtrain @ theta.T)-y),2)
    return np.sum(tobesummed)/(2 * len(xtrain))

#gradient descent
def gradientDescent(xtrain,ytrain,theta,iters,learn):
    cost = np.zeros(iters)
    for i in range(iters):
        z =(xtrain @ theta.T)
        theta = theta - (learn/len(xtrain)) * np.sum(xtrain * (xtrain @ theta.T - ytrain), axis=0)
        cost[i] = computeCost(xtrain, ytrain, theta)

    return theta,cost

#running the gd and cost function
g,cost = gradientDescent(xtrain,ytrain,theta,iters,learn)
print(g)

finalCost = computeCost(xtrain,ytrain,g)
print(finalCost)
```

Comment: A (33,1) would work here, but not (33,).  numpy can only expand it to (1,33), which doesn't help,

Comment: It is hard to tell from just reading the code the shape of arrays in the calculation.  You'll have to debug that yourself.

Comment: Which don't you understand, the broadcasting rules, or why you have this particular combination of array shapes at this point?

Comment: Solved it. Thank You all